# How to calculate the number of permutations and combinations if k is equal to n?

Tags: permutations, factorial, combinations

Say the question is

> How many unique ways are there to arrange the letters in the word FANCY?

The formula I use for permutations is `n! / (n - k)!`

Combinations formula I use is `n! / ( k! * (n - k)! )`

In this case, I would be dividing by zero in both cases. What universal formula can I use for situations where k might be equal to or larger than n?

Thank you

Comment: By definition, $0!=1$. If $k$ is larger than $n$, where $k$ and $n$ are non-negative integers, then by convention $\binom{n}{k}=0$. For FANCY, maybe it is best not to think in terms of formulas. The first letter can be chosen in $5$ ways, and for **each** of these the second letter can be chosen in $4$ ways and so on, so the answer is $(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that 0! = 1. 
I need to use a formula because I'm programming a function that calculates the number of permutations for any given n and k. 

You can submit your answer so I can formally accept it if you want.

Otherwise, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You are welcome. I think you will find that most programming language and calculator implementations of factorial do give the (right) answer $1$ at $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $0!=1$. There are a number of different justifications for this. One of them is that this choice makes the formulas you quote give the right answer. One can also argue that there really **is** exactly one way to choose $0$ objects from $n$: just say no in turn to each of them.

When $k$ and $n$ are non-negative integers, and $k\gt n$, we have two choices for $\binom{n}{k}$. We could say it is *undefined*. But it is more convenient to adopt the convention that in that situation, $\binom{n}{k}=0$. Again one could give an informal justification, there are $0$ ways to choose $5$ people from $3$. But the real reason for the convention is that it makes some formulas less messy.

Answer (score 1):

For the word FANCY:

- The number of members we have is *n=5* (F,A,N,C,Y)
- The number of selection from the member is *k=5* (as well)

  So n!/(n-k)! = 5!/(5-5)! = 5!/0! = 5! (as 0! = 1)
  The final result is 120

Another way of doing this is consider them as slots:

- for slot 1 we have **5** members to choose from {F,A,N,C,Y}
- for slot 2 we have **4** members **left** to choose from ({F,A,N,C,Y} - {whatever chosen at slot1})
- for slot 3 we have **3** members **left** to choose from ({F,A,N,C,Y} - {whatever chosen at slot1 and slot2})
- for slot 2 we have **2** members **left** to choose from ({F,A,N,C,Y} - {whatever chosen at slot1, slot2 and slot3})
- for slot 3 we have **1** members **left** to choose from ({F,A,N,C,Y} - {whatever chosen at slot1 and slot2})

Multiply all the possible options we have from each slot we got

```
    1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5
```

which is 5!

If you are interested in understand combination and permutation more, this might be a very interesting link: https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html